# The relation between the weak gravity conjecture and wormholes

Tags: cosmology, gravity, black-holes, wormholes

Charged black holes are usually associated with the [weak gravity conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_gravity_conjecture) at extremal limit, according to the well-known relation, i.e. charge to mass ratio. Now my question is that how the weak gravity conjecture and wormholes are related?

Comment: This question is a little vague and should probably be clarified. They are definitely both interesting aspects of gravity. Related in what sense? What context are you interested in?

Comment: I gave a small explanation above, for example, its relations with a black hole through mass and charge leads to changes in the block hole calculations. Now the question, is it possible to somehow introduce the relations between the weak gravity conjecture and issue of wormholes? Like this charge/mass>1 relation associated with black holes and WGC?

Comment: wormholes are black hole solutions so the WGC applies to them too. in fact the most common wormhole solution people consider in the literature is the eternal Schwarzschild black hole. the statement about the charge to mass ratio of these BHs is the same

Comment: although there are interesting subtleties in eternal AdS-Schwarzschild BHs, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07911)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help